# Button to copy image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image, copy

This seems like a ridiculously easy question but I can't find the answer.

I am creating a customer-facing page for my client, which will allow the user to filter through 1000+ charts by selecting region, product etc.

For each .png chart there is a matching table created dynamically as SVG. For each chart/table there should be several easy options to copy or save what they see.

[image]

Is there a reliable, cross browser way to do the second button, i.e. to copy the image to the clipboard (e.g. so the user can paste into powerpoint). I realise they can right click but some of them will not know this.

Sorry if this is obvious!

Emma

Comment: share your code please?

Comment: Copying to clipboard is still something sensitive, partly due to flash but you might be able to trigger a right click on the image with a left-click on the button (not sure here) in an attempt to display the context menu that allows you to copy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't copy images to the clipboard. Copying anything to the clipboard is a security limitation of every browser. You should indicate your user how can he do it, and trust him

Comment: This is what I feared. Thanks.